# Ping and curl resolve to one IP, dig/nslookup/host resolve to another

Tags: macos, dns, ping

OK, I have a very interesting case. I have a custom DNS server that is vending out IP addresses to varying servers in my test network. If I use `dig`, `nslookup`, or `host`, it tells me that it's properly resolving the IPs. If I `ping` or `curl` the hostname, it resolves to the actual external internet IP.

In my Network settings, I have only my custom DNS server, and this is correctly reflected in `/etc/resolv.conf`. I do not have this host in my `/etc/hosts`. If I add them, it will work, but I have multiple hosts that I'd have to add and remove, and I really want to know why this isn't working.

I've tried dumping the DNS cache using both `dscacheutil` and restarting mDNSResponder. This has had no effect. If I lookup the hostname via `dscacheutil`, it resolves incorrectly.

Clearly, Directory Services is messed up somehow. I've opened up Directory Utility, but I'm not too sure what to look for there.

Running `dscacheutil -configuration` shows:

```
azkaban:dnstest kylar$ dscacheutil -configuration

DirectoryService Cache search policy:
    /Local/Default

Unable to get details from the cache node
Unable to get cache configuration information
```

Any suggestions as to what to look for next? Also note that I'm using fully qualified domain names, i.e., foo.example.com or www.example.com.

***UPDATE:***
I also have a VPN enabled, but it's second in the Network list. The VPN is vending me a "lookup domain" that is the same as the domain that I'm trying to lookup. Somehow it's vending me a DNS server that is overriding the DNS server that I have set (Looks like a case of most-specific lookup). How can I tell it NOT to look via that server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I found it. The VPN config was auto-configuring it's own DNS servers, which were overriding my setup, because the VPN was also telling it to look up hosts in the domain that I was overriding. This caused the Directory Services to use the VPN vended DNS servers.

To fix, I added my custom DNS server as the first lookup entry under the VPN DNS config, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently as well. Thanks to Kylar's reply I was able to piece a few things together. I was **not** using a VPN, however, I was plugged into Ethernet, and my WiFi was still enabled as well.

Even tho WiFi was second in the Network list (and even tho the DNS servers were the same for both), I thought maybe there could be some internal issue where something wasn't updating properly?

So I turned off my WiFi connection and tested it again (solely on Ethernet), everything worked fine, curl & dig both resolved to the same IP. Really strange.

So then I tried to reenable WiFi, and it remained, curl & dig both resolved to the same IP.

So it seems that disabling and reenabling WiFi fixed the issue. I'm still not sure exactly why this fixed the issue, but it did for me, so I figured I'd share my findings here in case it helps someone else.